Creating a custom trigger in Automatewoo
I have created a few custom triggers in Automatewoo already based on this documentation https://woo.com/document/automatewoo/triggers/custom-triggers/, and they work great.
However, I am trying to create a more complicated one and running into some issues.
What I am trying to do is pass the product_id, product_name, and date_created to automatewoo so that I can include them in the email that is sent out.  I've looked around and couldn't find any examples of custom triggers that had custom data passed to automatewoo.
Here is the code I already have:
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Prevent direct access
}

/**
 * This is an example trigger that is triggered via a WordPress action and includes a user data item.
 * Trigger with: do_action('product_created', $user_id );
 */
class Product_Created_Trigger extends AutomateWoo\Trigger {

    /**
     * Define which data items are set by this trigger, this determines which rules and actions will be available
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $supplied_data_items = array('product');

    /**
     * Set up the trigger
     */
    public function init() {
        $this->title = __( 'Product Created', 'automatewoo-custom' );
        $this->group = __( 'Products', 'automatewoo-custom' );
    }

    /**
     * Add any fields to the trigger (optional)
     */
    public function load_fields() {}

    /**
     * Defines when the trigger is run
     */
    public function register_hooks() {
        add_action( 'product_created', array( $this, 'catch_hooks' ), 9999, 2 );
    }

    /**
     * Catches the action and calls the maybe_run() method.
     *
     * @param $user_id
     */
    public function catch_hooks( $product, $product_id ) {
        
        // Get the product name.
        $product_name = $product->get_name();
        $date_created = $product->get_date_created(); // Get the date created.
            
        $this->maybe_run(array(
            'product' => $product,
            'product_name' => $product_name,
            'product_SKU' => $product_id,
            'created_date' => $date_created,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Performs any validation if required. If this method returns true the trigger will fire.
     *
     * @param $workflow AutomateWoo\Workflow
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validate_workflow( $workflow ) {

        // Get objects from the data layer
        $product = $workflow->data_layer()->get_product();
        $product_name = $workflow->data_layer()->get_item( 'product_name' );
        $product_SKU = $workflow->data_layer()->get_item( 'product_SKU' );
        $created_date = $workflow->data_layer()->get_item( 'created_date' );

        return true;
    }
}

// This is in my functions.php
add_filter( 'automatewoo/triggers', 'product_created_trigger' );
/**
 * @param array $triggers
 * @return array
 */
function product_created_trigger( $triggers ) {

    include_once 'woocommerce/automatewoo/product_created_trigger.php';

    // set a unique name for the trigger and then the class name
    $triggers['product_created_trigger'] = 'Product_Created_Trigger';

    return $triggers;
}

This works in so much as the trigger shows up however I can't find the product_id, product_name, and date_created variables anywhere.  Is there something I am missing in my code or are there more steps I need to take?

It's just {{your_key}}
So, in your case, it's: {{product_name}}, {{product_SKU}}, {{created_date}}
I haven't tested yet to see whether objects are passed with object notation, i.e. if we pass an array or object can you access with {{custom_arg.product_name}}, etc., so I can't comment on the product object you passed over
Just set it up and test it and you can see if the data comes across in the logs / queue.
